# Rate of O exchange with H2O

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, covalent-compounds

We have to find the order of rate of exchange of O with H2O of the following compounds

1. $\ce{CCl3CHO}$
2. $\ce{CH3CHO}$
3. $\ce{CH3COCH3}$
4. $\ce{CF3CHO}$

According to me, higher rates of exchange would be when electron density is be less on the carbonyl carbon

But how we will compare 1. & 2.? In first compound there is hydrogen bonding (chloral hydrate)

Comment: 1 isn't chloral hydrate, it is just plain chloral.

Comment: @SendersReagent but there is hydrogen bond

Comment: No, that's not true. There is a hydrogen. There is no hydrogen bond. It is an aldehyde, which means there a hydrogen coming off the *carbon*.

Comment: @SendersReagent the product will have hydrogen bonding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you talk about the *rate of exchange of oxygen with water* it might be instructive to realise that actually any aldehyde or ketone in the presence of water is in equilibrium with the hydrate, as shown below.

> [image]
>
> ***Source***: UC Davis

There are a few ways we know that this is indeed an equilibrium process, but the main method that was used to fully elucidate the mechanism was by using isotopically labelled water containing 18O (the most abundant isotope of oxygen is 16O).

By doing this the scientists could observe the 16O in the starting aldehyde being slowly replaced with 18O from the enriched water.

Given that an equilibrium is involved, there are actually **two** pertinent questions...

1. What is the **position of the equilibrium**?
2. **How fast** do we reach the equilibrium?

The table below might be of some use to you. On the left, you can see a variety of carbonyl compounds, and on the right, the equilibrium constants for the hydration.

Two of the compounds you listed (acetaldehyde and trifluoroacetaldehyde) are listed in the table, and you can see that the acetaldehyde is significantly less hydrated at equilibrium than the trifluoroacetaldehyde.

> [image: Equilibrium constants for carbonyl compounds in water]
>
> ***Source:*** *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1983**, *105*, 868 (American Chemical Society)

From the table, some trends can be picked out (excluding formaldehyde which is almost exclusively hydrated). There is here a relationship between kinetics and thermodynamics (the more favourable a compound is to form the hydrate, the faster it will form it)

1. Aldehydes are far more likely to be hydrated than ketones. This is *largely* though not exclusively a steric effect.
2. Electron withdawing/electronegative substituents favour hydration. On a very simple level this is due to the fact that they make the carbonyl more electron poor, thus promoting the addition of water via its lone pair.

The order should therefore be 4>1>>2>3   (fluorine is more electron withdrawing than chlorine)

Comment: it means for reactivity the stability of product does not play a role

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The more electron withdrawing the moieties are the faster will be the exchange. $\ce{CCl3}$ is more electronwithdrawing than $\ce{CH3}$. So 1 will exchange oxygen faster than 2. Presence of chloral hydrate indicates fast rate of oxygen exchange.

http://chemistry2.csudh.edu/rpendarvis/imineformF99.html

By the way, note that chloral hydrate and chloral are two different compounds. Chloral hydrate is literally a chloral to which one molecule of water was added. Chloral hydrate is an intermediate in the oxygen exchange process.

[image]

Comment: I want to compare between compound 1 & 4 .

Comment: @koolman CF3 is more electronwithdrawing group than CCl3. It means that CF3COH exchanges water faster than CCl3COH

Comment: but the product with CCl3 is more stable due to hydrogen bonding

Comment: (1) CF3COH also forms floural hydrate ( you can buy it here; http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/68351?lang=en&region=US). (2) Stability of the product is important in thermodynamics, but here we discuss kinetics.

Comment: it means for reactivity the stability of product does not play a role