# Does -M Effect increases rate of hydration of aldehyde and ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I saw somewhere written, the rate of hydration of carbonyl compounds depends on:

1. -I group
2. Steric hindrance
3. Intramolecular H bonding

Can -M effect also increases rate of hydration?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55090/rate-of-o-exchange-with-h2o

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/90828/rate-of-formation-of-hydrate-in-a-carbonyl-compound